# SQLAlchemy: create many-to-many and populate association

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

My idea is the following:

- There is a main table (`Documents`) which contains some texts, e.g. blog posts. Each document has a unique id `text_id`.
- There is a secondary table (`Links`) which stores unique urls that appear in these posts. Each url has a unique id `url_id`.
- These are tied by an association table (`Association`), which maps an id of a text to an id of a domain.

I want to be able to get the posts, collect urls from those, and then:

- create a new record in `Documents`
- if it contains new urls - add them to `Links` and relate to the document through `Association`
- if a doc contains already existing urls - only create an association between the new document and those.

For starters, I created three classes like [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object):

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    text_id = Column('text_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.text_id'), primary_key=True)
    url_id = Column('url_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.url_id'), primary_key = True)
    child = relationship("Links", back_populates='parents')
    parent = relationship("Documents", back_populates='children')

class Documents(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    text_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    text = Column(Text)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates='parent')

class Links(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    url_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    url = Column(Text, unique=True)
    parents = relationship('Association', back_populates = 'child')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Then I am trying to load the data:

```
data = [
    {'id':1, 'text':'sometext', 'url':'facebook.com'},
    {'id':2, 'text':'sometext', 'url':'twitter.com'},
    {'id':3, 'text':'sometext', 'url':'twitter.com'}
]

for row in data:
    d = Document(text_id = row['id'])
    a = Association()
    a.child = Links(url = row['url'])
    d.children.append(a)
    session.add(d)
session.commit()
```

Which results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-325b1cd57576>", line 5, in <module>
    p.children.append(a)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1240, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1214, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: append
```

I really don't get why, as it seems I have done everything like an official documentation suggests.

For another thing, even if this works, I suspect that appending an already existing url through `p.children.append(a)` might result in an error, as it will essentially try to create a duplicate, and `Links` does not allow that.

I'm using mySQL and MariaDB if that matters.

Perhaps I have chosen a wrong tool for the job - I would be grateful if you could suggest what may be an alternative.

UPD: I could not insert because I instantiated a base with `automap_base()` instead of `declarative_base()`. Now I can append, however, the duplicate entries are indeed a problem:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'twitter.com' for key 'url'")
[SQL: INSERT INTO `right` (url) VALUES (%(url)s)]
[parameters: {'url': 'twitter.com'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it will be easier to debug if you use proper domain names instead of: `right`, `left`, `child`, `children`. I know that is a copy from docs, but docs are generic while your case is specific. Your code will be much more readable.

To avoid duplicates you should check before insert that record already exist (`Documents` have unique `text_id`, `Links` have unique `url`).

```
for row in data:
    d = session.query(Document).filter_by(text_id=row['id']).first()
    if not d:
        d = Document(text_id=row['id'])
    link = session.query(Links).filter_by(url=row['url']).first():
    if not link:
        link = Links(url=row['url'])
    a = Association(child=link)
    d.children.append(a)
    session.add(d)
    session.flush()
session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! And yeah, I'll pay more attention to naming next time :)